# Substitution of ! with sed leads to event not found

Tags: sed, csh, tcsh

I need to change every occurrence of `!` to `:` as field separators in a group file.

```
sed 's/!/:/g' filename > newfilename
```

But I get the error `/: Event not found`?

Comment: works for me (tm) `$ echo 'this!is!a!test!line' | sed 's/!/:/g'
this:is:a:test:line` can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I get "/: Event not found.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using `csh` so the `!` is being interpreted to fix this escape the `!` or just use `bash`:

```
sed 's/\!/:/g' file > outfile
```

With `csh` the `!`  used for command history reference and it works even inside a pair of apostrophes `'` or quotation marks `"`, unless escaped with a backslash `\`.

Comment: Awesome, I'll definitely keep note of this exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would verify the file existence and file permissions maybe, because the sed line works just fine:

```
[root@hacklab5 ~]# cat /tmp/sed.org 
dewed!Ddew!de
dewwe!ds!dewe
[root@hacklab5 ~]# sed 's/!/:/g' /tmp/sed.org 
dewed:Ddew:de
dewwe:ds:dewe
[root@hacklab5 ~]# sed 's/!/:/g' /tmp/sed.org > /tmp/sed.new
[root@hacklab5 ~]# cat /tmp/sed.new 
dewed:Ddew:de
dewwe:ds:dewe
```

Comment: I get an /: Event not found